# convert vb6 StrConv(string, vbunicode) to c#

Tags: c#, vb6-migration

I'm having trouble converting the following VB6 code into c#4.0? This function takes a BLOb from an oracle database and converts it to bytes. After removing the code un-needed by this example, it looked something like this...

```
Function tempFunc(Data as Variant) as byte()

    tempFunc = StrConv(Data, vbUnicode)

End Function
```

after converting the function to c#...

```
byte[] tempFunc(object data) 
{ 
    ...code...
}
```

I tried to convert the inner line but got to a problem...

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.StrConv(data, VBStrConv.???);
```

There isn't a Unicode equivalent flag in the VBStrConv enum any more...
looked up a few other examples and found this...

```
byteData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
```

However this takes a string and therefore is unhelpful...
Found another example using a memory stream however to convert it, it would need metadata, which would not exist in the original BLObs from the database.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)**

```
private byte[] tempFunc(object obj) 
{
    if(obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: [See also here: **Object ByteArray Converter and Vice Versa**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7450/Object-ByteArray-Converter)

Comment: Does this not require metadata for it to serialize the memory stream?